# Adding the "Do Not Backup" attribute to a folder hierarchy in iOS 5.0.1

Tags: iphone, ios

Referencing [iCloud + Storage of media in iPhone Documents folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7762743/icloud-storage-of-media-in-iphone-documents-folder), which shows how to set the iOS 5.0.1 "Do Not Backup" attribute for a file.

Is there an efficient way to do this for an entire folder/file hierarchy? E.g., my app creates /Library/PrivateDocs, and populates that with several folders, sub-folders, and files. Can I just set the do-not-backup attribute on the top-level folder, or must it be set on every individual file and folder under that also?

And, if it must be set on each file/subfolder, what's an efficient way to do so?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You could put one specific directory inside the documents dir for this purpose, put everything inside and only mark that single directory as do-not-backup using the

```
 addSkipBackupAttributeToItemAtURL
```

method shown in the article you linked, or use this one that uses a path instead of an URL:

```
+ (void)addSkipBackupAttributeToPath:(NSString*)path {
    u_int8_t b = 1;
    setxattr([path fileSystemRepresentation], "com.apple.MobileBackup", &b, 1, 0, 0);
}
```

example using a directory:

```
NSString *docsDirPath = [(AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] applicationDocumentsDirectory];
NSString *yourContentsDirPath = [docsDirPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:gContentsDirName];

[Utilities addSkipBackupAttributeToPath:yourContentsDirPath];
```

[EDIT]

I forgot this method use in the delegate to get the documents dir:

```
- (NSString *)applicationDocumentsDirectory {

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *basePath = ([paths count] > 0) ? [paths objectAtIndex:0] : nil;
    return basePath;
}
```

Comment: I had to include #include<sys/xattr.h> in older SDK 4.3 APP.

Comment: Do I call this once on app open? or every time I write to the folder?

Comment: if you solve the problem. Then explain it in brief.once on app open? or every time.

Comment: You call this when you create the folder. you don't have to set it every time. only once.

Comment: Does this work on hidden folders also?  If we enable the "external storage" flag on a binary data field in a core data model, core data will create a hidden folder in the same folder as your DB.  Unfortunately, you cannot set this attribute using this technique on the hidden folder that gets created.  If we move one level higher than where the DB sits and set the do not backup flag will it also fully propagate to hidden folders as well?

Answer (score 9):

For all my friends here, who needs in Swift - just look below (iOS8.0)

```
func addSkipBackupAttributeToItemAtURL(URL:NSURL) ->Bool{

let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
assert(fileManager.fileExistsAtPath(URL.absoluteString))

var error:NSError?
let success:Bool = URL.setResourceValue(NSNumber.numberWithBool(true),forKey: NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey, error: &error)

if !success{

    println("Error excluding \(URL.lastPathComponent) from backup \(error)")
}

return success;

}
```

Comment: this throws an error in swift 2 in line: let success:Bool = URL.setResourceValue(NSNumber.numberWithBool(true),forKey: NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey, error: &error)  //Extra argument 'error' in call

Comment: you're right its changed in swift 2.1  - no more error attribute now

Comment: I have updated the code for anyone using swift 2 in an answer below

Answer (score 2):

For me, in Swift, the previously answered functions didn't quite work.  In particular the assert line failed.  I needed to update it from URL.absoluteString! to URL.path!  So in the end mine looks like this:

```
func addSkipBackupAttributeToItemAtURL(URL:NSURL) ->Bool{

    let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
    assert(fileManager.fileExistsAtPath(URL.path!))

    var error:NSError?
    let success:Bool = URL.setResourceValue(NSNumber(bool: true),forKey: NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey, error: &error)

    if !success{
        println("Error excluding \(URL.lastPathComponent) from backup \(error)")
    }

    return success;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

maybe this would help someone using swift 2:

Just before `@UIApplicationMain` add this:

```
extension NSFileManager{
    func addSkipBackupAttributeToItemAtURL(url:NSURL) throws {
        try url.setResourceValue(true, forKey: NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey)
    }
}
```

In your `lazy var persistentStoreCoordinator: NSPersistentStoreCoordinator? = {` after you declare your URL you can add this:

```
 do {
            let url = url
            try NSFileManager.defaultManager().addSkipBackupAttributeToItemAtURL(url)

        } catch {
            // Handle error here
            print("Error: \(error)")
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

Correction on above method,use this for swift

```
 func addSkipBackupAttributeToItemAtURL(URL:NSURL) ->Bool {

    let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
    assert(fileManager.fileExistsAtPath(URL.absoluteString!))

    var error:NSError?
    let success:Bool = URL.setResourceValue(NSNumber(bool: true),forKey: NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey, error: &error)

    if !success{

        println("Error excluding \(URL.lastPathComponent) from backup \(error)")
    }

    return success;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you can do the following in `swift`:

```
func addSkipBackupAttributeToItemAtPath(path:String) -> Bool {


    let filePath = path.fileSystemRepresentation()
    let attrName  = "com.apple.MobileBackup"

    var attrValue : uint_fast8_t = 1

    let result = setxattr(filePath, attrName, &attrValue, sizeof(attrValue.dynamicType), 0, 0)

    return result == 0
}
```