# Can I use iphoneSetDoNotBackupFile on a folder of files rather than individual files?

Tags: ios, livecode

Do you know if I can use this on a folder and all the files within that folder will not be backed up? (in other words a folder rather than a file)  I have a lot of code written accessing PDF files within several folders located in the special path documents folder.  It would be pretty easy for me to set the do not back up of each one of those 7 folders but would rather not set the do not back up on each one of the 300 files within those 7 folders.

The same PDF`s folders also exist on my web server and so they can be updated or replaced if needed from there in the event they get deleted.  Do you think Apple would be OK with me leaving them in the Documents/PDFDIR folders and setting the do not back up of those (7) folders?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question was asked in a private support context, however, I felt it was valuable to answer here for others.

Yes it is. This property is recursive. While it's not really a duplicate answer because it's about a different language there is this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8694112/adding-the-do-not-backup-attribute-to-a-folder-hierarchy-in-ios-5-0-1) that backs up my answer in objective-c.