# Apps must follow the iOS Data Storage Guidelines or they will be rejected in app that contains .pdf

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have created an ebook and ePaper app and my app contains a lot of images and pdf files and I was putting the downloaded images , pdf files Documents directory

**Image directory:**

```
           NSString *strPageURL = [dictPage valueForKey:@"imagelink"];
            strPageURL = [strPageURL stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@""];
            strPageURL = [strPageURL stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\t" withString:@""];
            strPageURL = [strPageURL stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];

            NSString* strFileName = [strPageURL lastPathComponent];
            NSString *strDestFile = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Documents/%@",strFileName]];
```

**Pdf Directory**

```
          NSString *strThumbURL = [dictPage valueForKey:@"thumbimage"];
            //  NSLog(@"%@",strThumbURL);
            NSString* strThumbName = [strThumbURL lastPathComponent];
            NSString *strThumbPath = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Documents/%@",strThumbName]];

            BOOL fileExists = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:strThumbPath];
```

**How do I prevent files from being backed up to iCloud and iTunes?**

--------------------------**how to implement this method in my code**-----------------------------------

```
- (BOOL)addSkipBackupAttributeToItemAtURL:(NSURL *)URL
{
assert([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath: [URL path]]);

NSError *error = nil;
BOOL success = [URL setResourceValue: [NSNumber numberWithBool: YES]
                              forKey: NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey error: &error];
if(!success){
    NSLog(@"Error excluding %@ from backup %@", [URL lastPathComponent], error);
}
return success;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes your app may get rejected if you download large data and store it in Documents directory.
I have faced this problem.

read more here [iOS 5 does not allow to store downloaded data in Documents directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8209406/ios-5-does-not-allow-to-store-downloaded-data-in-documents-directory)

[Adding the "Do Not Backup" attribute to a folder hierarchy in iOS 5.0.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8694112/adding-the-do-not-backup-attribute-to-a-folder-hierarchy-in-ios-5-0-1)

Comment: then how to reslove this problem ?

Comment: see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8209406/ios-5-does-not-allow-to-store-downloaded-data-in-documents-directory. It may help you.

Comment: if we use Caches directory no need to implement addSkipBackupAttributeToItemAtURL method right

Comment: if i use document directory how to call addSkipBackupAttributeToItemAtURL

Comment: NSString *strDestFile = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Documents/%@",strFileName]];     NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:strDestFile]; [self addSkipBackupAttributeToItemAtURL:url];    It should work like this

Comment: @SurenderRathore : just wanted to confirm, using the code that you provided will approve the app... right?

Comment: @FahimParkar yes it apporved mine.