# iOS storing files rules - Storing audio files on iOS app

Tags: ios, ios5, nsdocumentdirectory

I need to be sure I am doing the right thing:

In my app the user can download audio files from the server. I don't want those big file to be backed up as he can re download them when ever he needs to.

My app is addressed for iOS 4.0 and above.

So as I understand I need to store the files is the documents directory and set a flag for the directory to not back up ?

Am I correct ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of putting them into the "Documents" directory (which gets backed up to the cloud), why not put your audio files into a "Cache" directory (specifically "`/Library/Cache`", which does not get backed up)?

[Here's another question here on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7762743/icloud-storage-of-media-in-iphone-documents-folder) that may help give a further answer to your question.

Comment: Won't those files be deleted when I empty the cache of the app ?

Comment: Yes... if you don't want to use "Cache", then set the "Do not backup" flag on whichever directory you decide to use (as specified in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8145650/981049)). The big issue here though is that this flag is 5.1 & newer only

Comment: What about the temp directory?

Answer (score 0):

You can also prevent files to backed up:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1719/_index.html